# GPO MSI Install - Error 1305.Error reading from file

Tags: windows-installer, adobe, verify, gpo

Windows Server 2016

Adobe Reader DC msi

Hi

I'm trying to install Adobe Reader remotely and silently to a set of PCs in a Windows Domain.
I have setup a network share, ABC-Deploy$, containing the Acroread.msi together with a GPO (software install) policy to effect this. So far I have not managed to get it working.

Having spent some time trying to isolate what I thought might be a policy failure, I decided simply to click on the MSI in the shared folder to see if it would install. I did this as an admin user on the server itself i.e. where the shared folder containing the msi resides. After the 'do you want to install' preamble the attempts fail with the following prompt:-

`Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\ABC-Deploy$\AcroRdrDC2200320282_en_US\AcroRead.msi.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.`

Clearly the file does exist as I have just clicked on it. I have researched this ad nauseam looking at share permissions, NTFS permissions, msiexec parms, admin user rights, clearing temporary files, clearing the registry etc all to no avail. I concentrated on permissions since the msiexec.exe runs under SYSTEM and I'm calling it from a domain admin user.

At present, the ABC-Deploy$ folder has the following permissions:-

| Share Permissions | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Everyone | Full Control |

| NTFS Permissions | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Everyone | Full Control |
| SYSTEM | Full Control |
| Local Admins | Full Control |
| ANONYMOUS LOGON | Read |
| All PCs (Domain Security Grp) | Read and Execute |
| sysadmin (Domain Administrator) | Full Control |

I have tried many, many permutations of permissions none of which seem to make any difference.

Any ideas how to resolve this anyone?

Thanks

Comment: I am not set up to test issues like these at the moment, suggest you check with the system administrators at: https://serverfault.com/ instead. Developers (Stackoverflow) typically don't deal with these kinds of things.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip Stein... I have added it at: https://serverfault.com/questions/1118218/gpo-msi-install-error-1305-error-reading-from-file